# Which embedded RDBMS should I use with Java? Why? What about backup and maintenance?

Tags: java, database, hsqldb, derby, h2

I'm relatively new to Java and using DBs with it, and I need help deciding which embedded RDBMS to use with a simple J2SE system. My criteria and concerns are: performance, low system requirements, reliability, easy of use/develop/deploy/maintain/backup/recovery.

**1) Before I was deciding between Firebird and SQLite, but then I've just met H2, HSQLDB and Apache Derby, and now I don't know which one to choose. Any of them would fit for me, but I need to explain why I choose one of them.
I believe I should use one of the native Java ones, since they can run inside the same JVM (which might use less resources). Which one do you suggest and why?**

**2) I also would like help on finding backup/recovery/maintenance manuals, tools and commands for H2, HSQLDB and Apache Derby, since I was not able to find this information on their website (not because the documentation is bad, most likely I'm a bad seeker)**

P.S: this might be a good source for others with the same problem, but be careful because the information is not fully up to date: http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/6-13-15-16-53/Apache-Derby-vs-Firebird-vs-HSQLDB-vs-H2-vs-SQLite

Comment: What aspect of the Derby documentation was unsatisfactory? The Derby documentation is extensive, in my opinion. Can you be specific?

Comment: I'm sorry, Derby documentation is very extensive, I was referring to my inability to find the information I wanted in it's documentation! I couldn't find how to fix and recover a corrupted database, for example.

Comment: HSQLDB backup documentation is here http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_backup

Answer (score 2):

H2 was written fairly specifically to be faster than HSQL and Derby. Its author has run some [benchmarks](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html) which, although they are rather old now, indicate that this goal was attained. According to those benchmarks, H2 is a bit faster than HSQL, and H2 and HSQL are much faster than Derby.

I don't know anything about management tools for any of these databases. Since they're embedded, they store their data in local files; it should therefore be easy to handle backup and restore by backing up and restoring their files.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Tom Anderson! After so much readings I guess I missed this performance tests in H2 website. I guess question (1) is already answered. But unfortunately question (2) is also a must-have.

Comment: Note that those benchmarks are fairly old -- recent indications are that HSQLDB/H2 are neck and neck again on basic performance: http://www.jpab.org/Hibernate/Derby/server/Hibernate/HSQLDB/embedded.html   -- That said, H2 is very configurable and can be tweaked for much higher performance in specific use cases.  It also does a better job of protecting against data loss than HSQLDB; one should NOT run HSQLDB in a production setting.

Comment: @BobMcGee: Interesting, thanks. Possibly the link that's most relevant here is: http://www.jpab.org/Hibernate/H2/embedded/Hibernate/HSQLDB/embedded.html though. Hopefully both databases will keep improving performance!

Comment: @TomAnderson That is a better link, yes.  All of the database engines shown there have made gigantic performance leaps in the last 3 or 4 years (especially Postgres).  With H2, it is particularly impressive given that it is mainly the work of one man: Thomas Mueller. Other developers (including myself) made much smaller contributions.  Mueller is a certifiable genius and a master of his art though, to do all that solo.